Next.js Instrumentation dynamic import with glob
Instrumentation in Next.js is able to use dynamic imports with hardcoded paths that are not variables:
export async function register() {
    console.log('[INSTRUMENATION] - process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME: ', process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME)

    if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs') {
        await import('./anyFile.ts')
    }
}

However, with globbed Paths I get this error:

Error: An error occurred while loading instrumentation hook: Cannot find module '/Projects/test/models/test/Test.model.ts'

With:
import { glob } from 'glob'
import path from 'path'

export async function register() {
    console.log('[INSTRUMENATION] - process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME: ', process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME)

    if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs') {
        // const expression = `${process.cwd()}/**/*.model.ts`
        
        const expression = path.join(process.cwd(), '/**/*.model.ts')
        const modelPaths = await glob(expression)

        for (const path of modelPaths) {
            console.log('globModels() -> path:', path)
            const doc = await import(path)
            console.log('doc:', doc.dbName)
        }
    }
}

I guess it has to do with webpack. Does anybody have a solution?
Using await import(/\* webpackIgnore: true \*/ path) with .mjs files is working but I want to use .ts files
